# npm:confirm the behavior of npm install for this case? Why there is no nested dependency?

Tags: npm

In application, I come across some issue when installing npm packages.

the package.json goes as following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "7.2.1",
    "privateLib": "19.0.0",
}
```

I only show the critical part and hide other things. The `privateLib` is one private package you can ignore the name.

And after `npm install`, it reports the  following `warn` message:

```
npm WARN privateLib@19.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/cdk@7.3.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

And I checked the installed `@angular/cdk` is  version `7.2.1`.

The confusing points is that, inside the `privateLib`, its own `package.json` config goes like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "7.3.7",
}
```

I checked there is no `@angular/cdk` package inside `privateLib`. So why it doesn't install its own dependency of version `7.3.7` in a `nested way`. This behavior is not same as the npm3 document: https://npm.github.io/how-npm-works-docs/npm3/how-npm3-works.html 
I'm using npm v6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, per https://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5:

> We will also be changing the behavior of peerDependencies in npm@3. We won’t be automatically downloading the peer dependency anymore. Instead, we’ll warn you if the peer dependency isn’t already installed. This requires you to resolve peerDependency conflicts yourself, manually, but in the long run this should make it less likely that you’ll end up in a tricky spot with your packages’ dependencies.

Try https://github.com/spatie/npm-install-peers to facilitate.